# Trying to automate to buy a shoe from Amazon

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/")
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Sign in").click()
driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys("** UR EMAILID **")
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(" ** UR PASSWORD **")
driver.find_element_by_id("signInSubmit").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("twotabsearchtextbox").send_keys("Mens shoes")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#nav-search > form > div.nav-right > div > input").click()
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Fashion Sneakers").click()
dropdown = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#native_dropdown_selected_size_name")  
select = Select(dropdown)
select.select_by_value("4,B01CE7QQPY")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='add-to-cart-button']").click()
```

I'm able to login, go to mens shoes and select fashion sneakers and select a type of shoe with particular size. Despite selecting its size, I'm not allowed to add to cart. The page says "select the size form the left to add to shopping cart". There are no errors on terminal/command line, but I'm unable to proceed. I have added a screenshot of the screen for reference as image below:

[[image: error]]

Comment: Can you try to `import time` and add `time.sleep(2)` before clicking `Add to cart`?

Comment: Ohh you are great!!! Thanks a lot it worked. I tried wait, Expected conditions what not but couldn't proceed. This was so easy never thought of using sleep.

Comment: It's not a good practice to use `sleep` because it's not a smart wait. It would be better to wait for whatever action is running to be completed using `WebDriverWait`.

Comment: Firstly i tried with webdriver wait it dint help. Sure i will keep in mind. Thanks for the suggestion.